# Index.android.js doesn't exist in Expo React-Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ot5LSGHLyY&t=1583s
I do not know why index.android.js does not exist. I research about it that it will really not exist if I build my project using Expo. If that is really the case, what should I do to get the same result on the tutorial that I'm following? Should I move to other tutorial and find like "Expo React-Native tutorial" or just ignore the part of index.android.js?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know what is Expo and Native. 
It's really confusing, so you can go through this [post](https://medium.com/@paulsc/react-native-first-impressions-expo-vs-native-9565cce44c92). It's really helpful.

It's expo when you have created your project with this command

```
create-react-native-app (a.k.a. CRNA)
```

Expo is doesn't has any index.android.js or index.ios.js file. Becuse you can

When you eject your expo project your project will go "**Native**". Which is equivalent to creating a project with this command

```
react-native init
```

This is a one-time command-line conversion that you cannot reverse except by rolling back your code from version control. In Native, you can write native code for android and ios respectively.

Comment: So if I eject my project from expo? There will be index.android.js now?

Comment: Yes there will be and you will find two folder also, android and ios

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature added to react-native. The new project template now doesn't contain two separate files. You can still use index js for android build as well iOS build. Its just a preference and the requirement of your project. You can find more info about the change on [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/6e99e314b232c315628c31f97a865c17c071ad23).